# Nested typealias is hiding outer type declaration

Tags: swift, types, nested

Given

```
class A {
    ...
}

class B {
    typealias A = Int
    ...
}
```

How do I declare an instance variable of class A inside the body of class B?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The typealias `A` is "shadowing" the other class type `A`.

One solution is to prefix the shadowed type with the module name, to tell the compiler that it's not the same type as the typealias one.

For example, if your module is named "MyApp", do:

```
class A {
    let test = "test"
}

class B {
    typealias A = Int
    let instance = MyApp.A()
}

let b = B()
print(b.instance.test)
```